# Websocket 8.5 sends `<Buffer>` to server. How to convert data on Server to JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm testing websocket connection. I want to send JSON object from client to Server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8082});

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log('server is connected');
  ws.on("message", (mesg) => {
    const a = mesg.toString();
    console.log(a);
  });
  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client has disconnected!");
  });
});
```

On the server side:
`console.log(mesg)` returns `<Buffer>`

`console.log(a)` returns `object Object]`

`JSON.parse(a)` throws error message.

I'm at a loss. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. You're saying console.log(a) is an object. console.log(a) is in the server code above. So you shouldn't try to convert an object to json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is on the client side. You're not serializing your JSON when sending it over the socket.

Add a call to `JSON.stringify()` on the client before sending, and it should work.

On the server then it's just a matter of using `JSON.parse(mesg.toString())` to output the buffer to a string and deserialize the JSON back to an object.

Comment: Thanks for this. Spent hours trying to figure out why `JSON.parse(msg)` was throwing errors. The `msg.toString()` part fixed it!